# Can't connect to Clickhouse using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, clickhouse

I can't connect to Clickhouse using Docker compose.

I have the following docker compose file:

```yaml
services:    
  my-clickhouse-db:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-server:23.9.1.1854-alpine
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 262144
        hard: 262144
    ports:
      - 18123:8123
      - 9000:9000

  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
      target: myService
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    depends_on:
      - my-clickhouse-db
```

And I use Clickhouse Java Client https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/java#java-client

Then I try to connecto to Clickhouse the following way from my-service:

```kotlin
val clickHouseNode = ClickHouseNode.of("http://my-clickhouse-db:18123")
val clickhouseClient = ClickHouseClient.newInstance(clickHouseNode.protocol)
clickHouseClient.read(clickHouseNode)
    .format(ClickHouseFormat.JSONEachRow)
    .query("select * from my_tabke")
    .executeAndWait()
    .records()
```

But I get an error:

```
com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseException: Connection refused, server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://my-clickhouse-db:18123/default]@-218511710
```

What do I do wrong? And how to fix the error?

Comment: `my-clickhouse-db` may take longer to come up than your code does to attempt the connection .   https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: @erik258 but my-clickhouse-db is available from a host of all the containers.

Comment: Also, I know that my-clickhouse-db is started when I try to connect to it.

Comment: You're trying to connect to port 18123, but it looks like the [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/clickhouse/clickhouse-server/) listens on ports 8123 and 9000 (connections between containers don't use `ports:` at all).  Does one of these other ports work better?

Comment: @DavidMaze wow, I replaced 18123 by 8123 and it works now! But why doesn't "18123:8123" work? I thought I map port 8123 in the container as port 18123 for consumers of the container. Am I wrong?

Comment: "(connections between containers don't use ports: at all)"
Could you please give me a link to documentation about this? I didn't know about this.
Also, you can post it as an answer to I accept it. :)

Comment: `ports:` maps a port on the host (that is, from outside Docker space entirely) to a port in the container; it's not "any consumer" but rather "connections to the host system".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you David! His [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77337283/cant-connect-to-clickhouse-using-docker-compose#comment136340527_77337283) answered my question. It turns out I misunderstood how port mapping works in Docker Compose, which caused me to use the wrong port to connect to Clickhouse. I should have used port 8123 from my-service to connect to Clickhouse.

The followin code works now.

```kotlin
val clickHouseNode = ClickHouseNode.of("http://my-clickhouse-db:8123")
val clickhouseClient = ClickHouseClient.newInstance(clickHouseNode.protocol)
clickHouseClient.read(clickHouseNode)
    .format(ClickHouseFormat.JSONEachRow)
    .query("select * from my_tabke")
    .executeAndWait()
    .records()
```